# Bait and switch fraud from a car dealer

Tags: fraud

Scenario: A car dealer claims that a car has a particular characteristic. A customer decides to purchase it. At the last moment, the car dealer claims that a mistake was made and that the car doesn't actually have that characteristic. The parties agree to lower the price and proceed with the purchase. The customer is later unhappy and accuses the dealer of having committed fraud by changing the deal at the last moment. The dealer backtracks and claims a further mistake and that the car did in fact have the characteristic all along.

Is this bait and switch fraud? Would there be any consequences to posting an online review stating that it is fraud?

Comment: Questions asking for legal advice are off-topic. I've edited your question to make it more generic.

Comment: @JBentley sorry for the extensive rewrite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

### Is it fraud?

It could be fraud by false representation under [Section 2 of the Fraud Act 2006](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2006/35/section/2):

> (1)A person is in breach of this section if he - (a) dishonestly makes
> a false representation, and (b) intends, by making the representation
> — (i) to make a gain for himself or another, or (ii) to cause loss to
> another or to expose another to a risk of loss.
>
> (2) A representation is false if — (a) it is untrue or misleading, and
> (b) the person making it knows that it is, or might be, untrue or
> misleading.

There are a lot of elements to be satisfied there. The dealer's claim has to have been untrue or misleading, the dealer has to have known that it was or might have been untrue or misleading at the time they made it, they have to have made the claim dishonestly, and they had to have intended to make a gain or cause a loss.

It's possible that all of that happened. It's also possible it was a mistake and they believed the claim to be true when they made it. In fact it does seem that it turned out to be true in the end. It's still possible that the second claim (that the car didn't have the characteristic) was fraudulent. But it's also possible that *that* was a mistake.

### Is it ok to claim that it is fraud in a public review?

Fraud is a very serious allegation to make, and it can have potentially big consequences for a business' reputation. A person making such an allegation publicly opens themselves up to the risk of being sued for defamation.